# What seem's to be wrong with this mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

This is just crazy. Nothing seems to be wrong with:

```
$q_messages = $db->query( "SELECT `messages`.`MessageID`, `messages`.`MsgDate`, `messages`.`MsgStatus`, " .
                "`messages`.`Subject`, `messages`.`Message`, CONCAT(users.LastName, ', ', users.FirstName) SenderName " .
                 "FROM `messages` " .
                 "INNER JOIN `users` ON `messages`.`Sender` = `users`.`UserID` " . 
                 "WHERE (`messages`.`Recipient`=$userid)" );
```

That query results in the following error been thrown:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\', \', users.FirstName) SenderName FROM `messages` INNER JOIN `users` ON `messa' at line
```

I've also tried replacing the ', ' with \", \" in the concat function, but that didn't fix it either. 
By the way, if I remove the second argument of the concat function, it works

PS. I ran the query in phpmyadmin, and it worked!

here's the echoed sql. Sorry I didn't realize what you meant by it at first :D

```
SELECT `messages`.`MessageID`, `messages`.`MsgDate`, `messages`.`MsgStatus`, `messages`.`Subject`, `messages`.`Message`, CONCAT(users.LastName, ', ', users.FirstName) SenderName FROM `messages` INNER JOIN `users` ON `messages`.`Sender` = `users`.`UserID` WHERE (`messages`.`Recipient`=30)
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that is surrounding this or show the echoed SQL that's causing the error?

Comment: In most of the cases, printing the "generated" SQL will show you immediately what is going wrong.

Comment: No, magic quotes are turned off. What is the echoed SQL? isn't the sql error??? in that error desc, the quotes are escaped. I don't know whyyyyyyyy

Comment: Something seems to be escaping your quotes in `', '`, which is messing up the query.

Comment: @ring0: no, and if it was, removing the ', ' shouldn't have solved it. but i'm sure that it ain't empty

Comment: @user1691367: By "echoed SQL", we mean ``echo "SELECT `messages`.`MessageID`..."``.  What does that print?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: You're dead right my man. And it's messing up head right now x-(

Comment: What is `$db`?  I'm assuming it's a MySQLi object.

Comment: Yes, and no. It an instance of class Database, which uses MYSQLi

Comment: @user1691367: Are you sure that `$db->query` isn't doing any escaping of the query passed to it?

Comment: I'm sure that it does :D. Sorry, thanks a gazillion times bro.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, you should add that as an answer so it can be accepted and this question won't remain open forever. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments, you said `$db` was a custom `Database` object.  Its `query` method may be escaping the string passed to it, which would cause it to escape the quotes around `', '`, thus breaking the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is the value of `$userid`.  For instance, if it is a character string, then it should be surrounded by quotes.

Also, when providing such queries, it is a good idea to show the actual SQL being sent.  That is, after the parameter substitutions.

Comment: @user1691367 . . . No, but you should check what value is actually being passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this concat:

```
CONCAT(users.LastName, ' , ', users.FirstName) as SenderName
```

I tested it and worked fine ;)

PS: Try to concat your query in a var, like:

```
$query = "select * from my_table";
$q_messages = $db->query($query);
```

In this way you can do an echo to $query and see what is happening ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot Rocket Hazmat, $db was escaping the query. It was a class I used on an earlier project, and I just reused it.

Comment: @user1691367: This isn't my answer.

Comment: I know, but since I stated your answer here, I wanted to save you the trouble of posting again. Thanks for helping